# Calculating the classical OR gate in a 3 qubit (+1 ancillary qubit) circuit

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, universal-gates

I have a 2 qubit (+1 ancillary qubit) circuit in Qiskit which calculates the classical OR gate (q0 or q1) as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer

for input in ['00','01','10','11']:
    
    mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(3,1)
    
    #Initialization - Note qiskit order
    if input[0] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(1)
    if input[1] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(0)

    mycircuit1.cx(0,2)
    mycircuit1.cx(1,2)
    mycircuit1.ccx(0,1,2)

    mycircuit1.measure(2,0)

    job    = execute(mycircuit1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000)
    counts = job.result().get_counts(mycircuit1)
    print("Input:", input, "Output:", counts)
```

that returns:

```
Input: 00 Output: {'0': 1000}
Input: 01 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 10 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 11 Output: {'1': 1000}
```

and and I want to expand it to a 3 qubit(+1 ancillary qubit) circuit that calculates (q0 or q1 or q2) but I do not know how. One way of thinking is that (q0 OR q1 OR q2) = (qo OR q1) OR q2
so I can put the gates from the previous circuit and repeat the process. However, I do not know how to bind these two together. Here is the circuit that I have at the moment:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer

for input in ['000','100','010','001', '110','011','101','111']:
    
    mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(4,1)
    
    #Initialization - Note qiskit order
    if input[0] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(1)
    if input[1] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(0)

    mycircuit1.cx(0,2)
    mycircuit1.cx(1,2)
    mycircuit1.ccx(0,1,2)

    mycircuit1.barrier()

    mycircuit1.cx(1,3)
    mycircuit1.cx(2,3)
    mycircuit1.ccx(1,2,3)
    
    mycircuit1.measure(3,0)

    job    = execute(mycircuit1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000)
    counts = job.result().get_counts(mycircuit1)
    print("Input:", input, "Output:", counts)
```

that returns:

```
Input: 000 Output: {'0': 1000}
Input: 100 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 010 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 001 Output: {'0': 1000}
Input: 110 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 011 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 101 Output: {'1': 1000}
Input: 111 Output: {'1': 1000}
```

I am stuck at this point and I do not know what to do next. As demonstrated in the results if q0 or q1 equals one, the final result would be one, so if I can fix the problem in the 001 input, I can say I implemented the classical OR gate for three inputs.

Comment: Have you looked at qiskit's append method for quantum circuits. You can append a whole circuit, specifying which qubits you're applying it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You only initialize the first two bits, the last bit of the input is unused. Thus, you should replace:

```python
    if input[0] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(1)
    if input[1] == '1':
        mycircuit1.x(0)
```

by (I've also replaced `input` by `input_` because `input` is a built-in):

```python
    for index, bit in enumerate(input_[::-1]):
        if bit == '1':
            mycircuit1.x(index)
```

2. You have to use 5 qubits in total, not 4: 3 to store the input bits, 1 to store `q0 or q1` and 1 to store `(q0 or q1) or q2`.

Thus, your code should look like this:

```python
for input_ in ['000','100','010','001', '110','011','101','111']:
    mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(5,1)
    
    # Reverse input_ because of qiskit order
    for index, bit in enumerate(input_[::-1]):
        if bit == '1':
            mycircuit1.x(index)

    mycircuit1.cx(0, 3)
    mycircuit1.cx(1, 3)
    mycircuit1.ccx(0, 1, 3)

    mycircuit1.barrier()

    mycircuit1.cx(2, 4)
    mycircuit1.cx(3, 4)
    mycircuit1.ccx(2, 3, 4)
    
    mycircuit1.measure(4,0)

    job    = execute(mycircuit1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000)
    counts = job.result().get_counts(mycircuit1)
    print("Input:", input_, "Output:", counts)
```

Note however that, as mentioned by DaftWullie in the comments, you can define a `QuantumCircuit` that you want to append to your main circuit. For instance, define:

```python
or_circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
or_circ.cx(0, 2)
or_circ.cx(1, 2)
or_circ.ccx(0, 1, 2)
```

And you can then do:

```python
for input_ in ['000','100','010','001', '110','011','101','111']:
    mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(5,1)
    
    # Reverse input_ because of qiskit order
    for index, bit in enumerate(input_[::-1]):
        if bit == '1':
            mycircuit1.x(index)

    mycircuit1.append(or_circ, [0, 1, 3])

    mycircuit1.barrier()

    mycircuit1.append(or_circ, [2, 3, 4])
    
    mycircuit1.measure(4,0)

    job    = execute(mycircuit1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000)
    counts = job.result().get_counts(mycircuit1)
    print("Input:", input_, "Output:", counts)
```

As a final note, since you know that `q0 OR q1` is equivalent to `NOT (NOT q0 AND NOT q1)`, you can define your `OR` gate with only `X` and `CCX` gates:

```python
or_circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
or_circ.x([0, 1, 2])
or_circ.ccx(0, 1, 2)
or_circ.x([0, 1])
```

Using this gate would still give you the right results.

---

Finally, note that you can use the same last trick to implement the `OR` gate with only 4 qubits: just use an `MCX` gate, which represents the logical `AND` and negate it:

```python
for input_ in ['000','100','010','001', '110','011','101','111']:
    mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(4, 1)
    
    # Reverse input_ because of qiskit order
    for index, bit in enumerate(input_[::-1]):
        if bit == '1':
            mycircuit1.x(index)

    mycircuit1.x(range(4))
    mycircuit1.mcx([0, 1, 2], 3)
    mycircuit1.x(range(3))
    
    mycircuit1.measure(3, 0)

    job    = execute(mycircuit1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000)
    counts = job.result().get_counts(mycircuit1)
    print("Input:", input_, "Output:", counts)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked and showed one way of implementing the classical or for 3 qubits. However, I must implement my solution using a total of 4 qubits (circuit = QuantumCircuit(4,1)). Is there any other way to implement the classical or?

Comment: @Hamideh I've updated the answer to add such a solution. Please have a look.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: What is the reason for putting the last set of Xs after mcx?

Comment: @Hamideh If your goal is only to compute the `OR` gate, it doesn't serve any purpose. The last layer of $X$ gates ensures that the first qubits are in the same state they were at the beginning of the computation. If you only want to compute the `OR` gate you can remove them, but if you want to use the OR gate as a routine within another algorithm (just like I did with the second version of `or_circ`), you have to add them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not answering the root of your question. I would like to point out that Qiskit has a boolean expression synthesiser that automatically does that:

```python
from qiskit.circuit.classicalfunction import BooleanExpression

circuitXorY = BooleanExpression("x or y").synth()
print(circuitXorY)
```

```
q_0: ──■───────
       │       
q_1: ──o────■──
     ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
q_2: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└───┘
```

With 3 qubits (plus one for the result):

```python
circuitXorYorZ = BooleanExpression("x or y or z").synth()
print(circuitXorYorZ)
```

```
q_0: ──■────────────
       │            
q_1: ──o────■───────
       │    │       
q_2: ──o────o────■──
     ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
q_3: ┤ X ├┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └───┘└───┘└───┘
```

You can see how is that implemented without open controls like this:

```
print(circuitXorYorZ.decompose())
```

```
q_0: ───────■───────────────────────────
     ┌───┐  │  ┌───┐                    
q_1: ┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├───────■────────────
     ├───┤  │  ├───┤┌───┐  │  ┌───┐     
q_2: ┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├──■──
     └───┘┌─┴─┐└───┘└───┘┌─┴─┐└───┘┌─┴─┐
q_3: ─────┤ X ├──────────┤ X ├─────┤ X ├
          └───┘          └───┘     └───┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was insightful. I am trying to build the same circuit in my code but it does not work. I do not know why.

Comment: I added the same example in terms of mcx. Maybe you can compare with yours.

Comment: Thanks. At this point, I do not know how to implement CCCX. :-)

Comment: you can do it with `MCX` (multi-controlled-not) `circuit.mcx([0,1,2], [3])`. See the docs in https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.mcx.html